# How to share byobu with multiple users?

Tags: byobu, tmux, gnu-screen, multiple-users

The best way to learn and troubleshoot is to pair up with someone else on the internet via text based screensharing.  Love the ergonomics of byobu for a single user at a single time.  However when I want to share my terminal session with one or more colleagues, I end up going back to plain screen and last night installed wemux.  But then we all miss out on byobu features.

The wemux package makes it easy to share the same terminal for multiple users, but did not seem byobu integrated.

screen has multiuser and acl settings, so some users are read only while others are rw.

Since byobu abstracts terminal usage so well, i was hoping it would abstract screen sharing as well.  Afterall, there is nothing better than dev-ops except dev-ops with a friend or group.  How do you screenshare using byobu layered on top of screen?   Byobu on top of tmux?

Comment: To be clear, these users are not already sharing the same username.  Different account logins need to see the same byobu session.